# A recursive function that appends the end of a linked list to the beginning of another and returns a pointer to the beginning of the new list

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, linked-list

I am having trouble figuring out how to have the function return the "Head" of the new list recursively. They append just fine, but recursively I cannot figure out how to "save my place" so to speak.

```
struct node {
    int value;
    node *next;
};

node* append(node *&L1, node *L2)
{
    if(L1->next == NULL) {
        L1->next = L2;
        return L1;
    }
    else if(L2 == NULL) 
       return L1;
    else 
       return append(L1->next, L2);
}
void main()
{
    node *a, *b, *c, *d;
    a=new node;
    b=new node;
    c=new node;
    d=new node;
    a->value = 4;
    a->next = b;
    b->next = NULL;
    b->value = 7;
    c->next = d;
    c->value = 12;
    d->next = NULL;
    d->value = 8;
    append(a,c);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are you writing linked lists like this?

Comment: Is your assignment to write a linked list implementation because otherwise you should be using STL with c++ [stl::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/?kw=list)

Comment: I think your code snippet as a prototype of link list will work, so what do you ask for?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase, I need it to return a pointer to the first node of the new list. When I return for example, L1->value, the value of the node is not the value I assigned. I left out where I declared the linked list since that is pretty irrelevant. I can add that in.

Comment: Right off the bat, check for a NULL `L1` before the dereference to check `L1->next`. Thats the very first immediate bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node* append(node *&L1, node *L2)
{
   if (L1 == NULL)
       L1 = L2;
   else if (L1->next != NULL)
       append(L1->next, L2);
   else
       L1->next = L2;

   // Return the head node of the linked list
   return L1;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, that looks similar to what I had just a little tweaking!

Answer (score 1):

Recursive function almost always have two components: base case and recursive case. So you have to first think what are those in your requirement?

For example, assuming you have two linked list: listA & listB:

1. *base case*: when listA has no more element, stop
2. *recursive case*: detach last element of listA, attach it to beginning of listB. Call the function again recursively

From above pseudo code you should have enough to start programming

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, you need to account for L1 being NULL on inception. Thankfully accounting for it also accounts for the actual append as well.

```
node *append(node *&L1, node* L2)
{
    if (!L1)
        L1 = L2;
    else
        append(L1->next, L2);
    return L1;
}
```

---

**How It Works**

Trivial Case `(L1 = NULL, L2 = <anything>>)`

1. Enter the function; `L1 = NULL` and `L2 = <<anything>>`
2. The `if(!L1)` is satisfied. We assign `L2` to `L1`, and return `L1`.

Regular Case: `(L1 != NULL, L2 = <anything>>)`

1. Enter the function; `L1 != NULL, L2 = <anything>>`
2. The `if(!L1)` is *not* satisfied, recurse, sending `L1->next, L2`
3. Continue recursing until `L1` is NULL (which will be the last `next` in the list, and is therefore the end), then assign L2 to that `L1` pointer (which again, is the last `next`).
4. Always return L1 for the result. The final back-out of the recursion will return the head of the list.